# Goal: stripping whitespace adjacent to certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

What I am doing:

```
> ' { foo ( bar: 8 ) { baz: 9 fun: bun } } '.replace(/\s[{}():]\s/g, '');
< "foobar: 8{ baz: 9 fun: bun} "
```

What I am trying to do:

```
> ???
< "{foo(bar:8){baz:9 fun:bun}}"
```

This has to do with compressing queries for sending from a client to a graphql server. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use capture group in the regex to replace the character without space :

```
> '{ foo ( bar: 8 ) { baz: 9 fun: bun } } '.replace(/\s*(\[|\]|\{|\}|\(|\)|\:)\s*/g, '$1')
< "{foo(bar:8){baz:9 fun:bun}}"
```

The parenthesis capture the expression, and `$1` allow you to use this expression.

Comment: Thanks for this. Lighter weight, and simpler than a full lexer. Wonder about performance, I'll take a look at that next.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid regexes won't suit your needs here, a proper library would be much more appropriate.

In the mean time, you can give a try to `.replace(/\B | \B/, "")`, but it for sure does not cover all the cases, plus certainly breaks some requests. This covers your example at least.

Comment: Yeah I thought I'd need a bit of a lightweight lexer of some sort. The evil part of me was thinking I could cut those corners somehow. Anyway, this is what I needed to confirm so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Was trying to avoid another external dependency, but this is doing what I need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-query-compress

Comment: @jerome Nice, exactly what you needed, thanks for sharing!

Comment: This package ends up with more effective compression than the regex below.